# Will the system initialize the variable innerPadding in function Scaffold automatically?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Compose, Code A is from the [article](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts#4).

I was told tthe following content:

*The body content that is of type @Composable (InnerPadding) -> Unit: the lambda receives a padding as a parameter.*

I'm very strange where the variable `innerPadding` is initialized, will the system initialize the variable `innerPadding` in function `Scaffold` automatically?

**Code A**

```
 Scaffold { innerPadding ->
        Text(text = "Hi there!", modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the source code and you will see that `Scaffold` is implemented as a [subcompose layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#SubcomposeLayout(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function2)). The bottom bar is subcomposed:

```
val bottomBarPlaceables = subcompose(ScaffoldLayoutContent.BottomBar) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalFabPlacement provides fabPlacement,
        content = bottomBar
    )
}.fastMap { it.measure(looseConstraints) }
```

`innerPadding` is then derived from the height of the bottom bar:

```
val bottomBarHeight = bottomBarPlaceables.fastMaxBy { it.height }?.height ?: 0

val innerPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = bottomBarHeight.toDp())
content(innerPadding)
```